# Django hCalendar microformat

Tags: django, microformats, hcalendar

Is there any django app out there that allows creating events in the hCalendar microformat? I'm looking for an app with a basic event data model, forms and templates that implement hCalendar markup! Just want to make sure I didn't miss something before doing it myself!

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Django Microformat Application](https://github.com/poswald/microformats)